# Linkedin Oauth Javascript authorization "uh oh!"

Tags: javascript, oauth, linkedin-api

I can't login on my app with Linkedin, i see modal linked dialog with "uh oh!"
What to do? Why don't work linkedin Oauth?

```js
function onLinkedInLoad() {
  IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", function() {onLinkedInLogin();});
  IN.Event.on(IN, "logout", function() {onLinkedInLogout();});
}
function onLinkedInLogin() {
  IN.API.Profile("me")
    .fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl", "publicProfileUrl", "emailAddress"])
    .result(function(result) {

      console.log(firstName);
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      alert(err);
    });
}
function liAuth(){
  // 
   IN.User.authorize(function(){
       callback();
   });
   //IN.UI.Authorize().place();
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: 54545645645646
    authorize: false
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>

<div onclick="liAuth()" class="loginsocbutton loginsocbutton__in" id="oauth_linkedin">click</div>
```

Comment: Please check my answer it's working properly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463713/customizing-linkedin-login-button/54566492#54566492

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to go to your applications permissions immediately and uncheck all boxes except the 4 that appear in this screenshot. I was able to get my integration working again after that.

[image]

They seem to not be handling revoked permissions very gracefully. You, like us, were probably not using those extra permissions anyways.

Comment: Thanks! For us we only had `r_basicprofile` checked which gave us the great error message of _uh oh!_ for all of our users. Enabling the `r_emailaddress` permission fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. This is the least helpful error message that I have seen.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what they're thinking over there at LinkedIn. They've quickly become my least favorite social network out there. They must be under new leadership.

Comment: I get the same error no matter what options I choose I get the message in a popup window "uh oh!"

Comment: @Throttlehead I am getting the same error after following your instructions.

Answer (score 2):

A change in LinkedIns API was rolled out today wrecking code everywhere.

you can read about it here:

https://developer.linkedin.com/blog
https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

Comment: Thank you. But i not understand, what i should do.

Answer (score 0):

Besides to Jacob's answer, you need to go to your app settings and make sure that all fields are filled in - particularly logos, contact details...basically all those details that were optional before now became required. This and re-setting the permissions should work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too.
Message "Uh Oh!" inside the popup window, when executing IN.User.authorize(). 
To solve this, I recreated from scratch a new LinkedIn application, but for the same website/URL. Then I inserted the new api_key.
And then it was working.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onLinkedInLoad() {
  IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", function() {onLinkedInLogin();});
  IN.Event.on(IN, "logout", function() {onLinkedInLogout();});
}
function onLinkedInLogin() {
  IN.API.Profile("me")
    .fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl", "publicProfileUrl", "emailAddress"])
    .result(function(result) {

      console.log(firstName);
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      alert(err);
    });
}
function liAuth(){
  // 
   IN.User.authorize(function(){
       callback();
   });
   //IN.UI.Authorize().place();
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: 54545645645646
    authorize: false
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>

<div onclick="liAuth()" class="loginsocbutton loginsocbutton__in" id="oauth_linkedin">click</div>
```