# Not able to impliment sign-in with twitter and linkedin

Tags: php

hey I  am sorry if this has been  asked before 
 I am new here i don't know how it can be done 
 I successfully impliment login with facebook and sign in with gmail but not able to sign in with twitter and linkedin don't know why?
 please help

For twitter i visited  `https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in` 
 don't no how to use it 
 also  `https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing.`

And for linkedin

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463713/customizing-linkedin-login-button/39826764#39826764
```

but this not even display linkedin button or image always display blank page

i spend 4-5 hours found nothing how to do them please help

Class 'OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1' not found

i tried various examples and m getting same error in each case don't know why? help me please

```
 function __construct($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token = NULL, $oauth_token_secret = NULL) {
    $this->sha1_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
    $this->consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
    if (!empty($oauth_token) && !empty($oauth_token_secret)) {
      $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
    } else {
      $this->token = NULL;
    }
  }
```

if i used require_once('OAuth.php'); then doesnot not display Fatal error: Class 'OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1' not found  but display errors like 
Undefined index: oauth_token  on

```
 function getRequestToken($oauth_callback) {
    $parameters = array();
    $parameters['oauth_callback'] = $oauth_callback; 
    $request = $this->oAuthRequest($this->requestTokenURL(), 'GET', $parameters);
    $token = OAuthUtil::parse_parameters($request);
    $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);
    return $token;
  }
```

Comment: `For twitter i visited` - You literally visited that URL in browser and expect your some JS code to work? Show us what have you done.

Comment: sorry i don't have that script now

Comment: So you wish for us to write code for you? Sorry, SO does not work like that, you write code and only when you face serious issue that you can't figure out, only than ask here (use google/SO to try resolve issue)

Comment: please see my edited question @Justinas 
how to solve this

Comment: Your code is `PHP`, but question labeled as `javascript`

Comment: now check i changed to php